# How to avoid receiving my messages twice when connected to a federation?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using AMQP protocol to send messages between applications. I use RabbitMQ as server.

I have a local RabbitMQ server running on computer "A". So different applications can send/receive message on computer "A" local network.

All messages are sent using a single "fanout" exchange named "MessageExchange" : when an application send a message on computer "A", every applications on computer "A" receive this message.

There is the same softwares installed for computer "B" and "C".

Now, computer "A", "B" and "C" are networked together by using a common, remote, RabbitMQ server configured to create a federation between all RabbitMQ local instances. Each RabbitMQ local instance is configured to "shovel" its messages to remote server.

Everything is working as intended : when an application send a message on exchange "MessageExchange" on computer "A", every application running on computer "A", "B" and "C" receive the message.

My problem is the following : if the application which send the message is on computer "A", every application on computer "A" receive the message twice : one message from local RabbitMQ server and one copy from remote federation.

How can I avoid this ?

Here is some additionnal informations :

- the remote RabbitMQ server can be disconnected at any time, the whole messaging system should continue to work (only on local network of course) whitout modifying local configuration
- to have this behavior (with or without the remote server connected) I use the same exchange name everywhere. This is probably the origin of my problem
- I have successfully filtered the message received twice by adding a header on remote server and implementing the filter in the different application, but I think the same can be done by playing with RabbitMQ/AMQP configuration, without writing code